# How do you select a parent element based on the text of it's child element WITHOUT jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been learning basic javascript functionality by using jQuery but now I am interested in learning how to perform the same actions with plain javascript. I have looked for clear answers on this but have failed to find an appropriate answer or direction for my situation. My question is how do you select a parent element based on the text of it's child element WITHOUT jQuery? I would like to remove the parent element of the label that has the text "lefse".

If I where to use jQuery I would simply do something like:

```
$('.BreadBasket .BreadSpec > label:contains("lefse")').parents('.BreadSpec ').remove();
```

But again I would like to use plain JS. Thank you!

```
<div class="BreadBasket">
<ul>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>brioche</label>
      <span>01</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>focaccia</label>
      <span>02</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>naan</label>
      <span>03</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>lefse</label>
      <span>04</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>tandoor</label>
      <span>05</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>tortilla</label>
      <span>06</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.querySelectorAll()`, `for..of` loop, check `.textContent` of current `label` element, call `ChildNode.remove()` on `.parentElement` if match is found, `break` loop

```js
for (let label of document.querySelectorAll(".BreadBasket .BreadSpec > label")) {
  if (label.textContent === "lefse") {
    label.parentElement.remove();
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="BreadBasket">
  <ul>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>brioche</label>
      <span>01</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>focaccia</label>
      <span>02</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>naan</label>
      <span>03</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>lefse</label>
      <span>04</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>tandoor</label>
      <span>05</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>tortilla</label>
      <span>06</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

If supported at browser, you can alternatively use `Array.from()`, `Array.prototype.find()`

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".BreadBasket .BreadSpec > label"))
.find(({textContent}) => textContent === "lefse")
.parentElement.remove()
```

```html
<div class="BreadBasket">
  <ul>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>brioche</label>
      <span>01</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>focaccia</label>
      <span>02</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>naan</label>
      <span>03</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>lefse</label>
      <span>04</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>tandoor</label>
      <span>05</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>tortilla</label>
      <span>06</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) DOM property:

```js
// Find all the labels that match your criteria
var labels = document.querySelectorAll('.BreadBasket .BreadSpec > label');

// Loop over the found elements
for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i){
  // Test for the condition. indexOf returns -1 if the specified
  // string is not found, otherwise it returns the index position 
  // of where the string was found.
  if(labels[i].textContent.indexOf("lefse") > -1){
     // When a match is found, get a reference to the parent node
     var parent = labels[i].parentNode;
     
     // There is no "removeParent" method, only "removeChild", so you have
     // to actually find the parent of the parent to be able to remove the
     // desired node. So, get the parent of that parent and use the 
     // removeChild() method
     parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="BreadBasket">
<ul>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>brioche</label>
      <span>01</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>focaccia</label>
      <span>02</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>naan</label>
      <span>03</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>lefse</label>
      <span>04</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>tandoor</label>
      <span>05</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>tortilla</label>
      <span>06</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what does the "> -1" mean when used in an if statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
var textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

// directly converting the found 'a' elements into an Array,
// then iterating over that array with Array.prototype.forEach():
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('label'), 0).forEach(function(aEl) {
  // if the text of the aEl Node contains the text 'lefse':
  if (aEl[textProp].indexOf('lefse') > -1) {
    // we update its style:
    aEl.parentNode.remove()

  }
});
```

Comment: `textContent` has wide support. There is really no reason to test for it. `innerText` also has wide support, but is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var liElements=document.getElementsByTagName('LABEL');
for(var i=0; i<liElements.length; i++){
  var elem=liElements[i];
  if(elem.innerHTML==='lefse'){
    var li=elem.parentNode;
    li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="BreadBasket">
<ul>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>brioche</label>
      <span>01</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>focaccia</label>
      <span>02</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>naan</label>
      <span>03</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>lefse</label>
      <span>04</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>tandoor</label>
      <span>05</span>
    </li>
    <li class="BreadSpec">
      <label>tortilla</label>
      <span>06</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```